# Setting default values in spinner in android

Tags: java, android

I am using a spinner using following code

```
   private String `DEFAULT_CURRENCY_TYPE`;


  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currenciesDataSource.keys); 
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            paidIn.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to do something like that `paidIn.setDefault(DEFAULT_CURRENCY_TYPE)`

Meaning whenever i create spinner it compare its values with my default values and then set it as first element. How can i do that?

Best Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(DEFAULT_CURRENCY_TYPE))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use spinner.setSelection(position) may be the solution if i understood your question clearly

Comment: how can i get the position !!