# Spinner Android (SetPrompt)

Tags: android, spinner

I am running into an issue with a spinner that I defined and bound to an array resource. The problem is that it "ONLY" defaults to the first item of the array when it is first constructed. I am using the setPrompt and it looks like it is being ignore totally. I wrote to the log and I can see in the log that I am setting it to the right value but it instead keeps defaulting to the first element in the array.

```
_spnCountDown.setPrompt(setting);
    Log.d("SETTING_SPINNER", setting);
    _spnCountDown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        boolean _firstTime = true;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            if (_firstTime == false)
            {
                String value = _spnCountDown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                MobileAppManager.getInstance().storeSetting("CountDown",
                        value);
                Log.d("SETTING_SPINNER onItemSelected", value);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("SETTING_SPINNER onItemSelected", "Ignore");
                _spnCountDown.setPrompt(Settings.this.getInitialCountDown());
                _firstTime = false;

            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

I have followed few answers that recommend using a flag to overcome the fact that onSetItemSelected will first the first time the spinner is constructed. So, rightfully so, I am ignoring the first call. However as I mentioned, It is defaulting to first entry.

[image: When it is first loaded]
[image: The whole list]

So, If this line will not do anything _spnCountDown.setPrompt("5 seconds")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but if I understand your question correctly this suggests perhaps you should use setSelection?
[Setting default values in spinner in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731618/setting-default-values-in-spinner-in-android)

Comment: You are right. I was thinking that setPrompt will implicitly set the value as well like Html Select/DropDown.

Thanks for noticing.